# Random numbers while loops

Tags: java

I am new to java and i am so close to the answers.i hope that i can have some hints but not the full answer.I will prefer to derive the logic out on my own.

```
/*
Write a method named makeGuesses that will guess numbers
between 1 and 50 inclusive until it makes a guess of at least 48.
It should report each guess and at the end should report
the total number of guesses made. Below is a sample execution:
*/

guess = 43
guess = 47
guess = 45
guess = 27
guess = 49
total guesses = 5

public void makeGuesses(){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rnd=new Random();
    int i=1
    int counter=0;

   while(i>=1 && i<=50){

        i=rnd.nextInt();
        System.out.println("guess = " + i);
         counter++;


    }
    System.out.print("total guesses = "+ counter);
}
```

What's wrong with my code?I realised although i fix my i to be between 1 and 50,it still exceeds.

Comment: This will print out 0-50 random numbers. like `guess = 10, guess = 50, guess = 73`. Is that what you want? And at the end it will print out the amount of cycles.

Comment: ya.That's what i want.But i am getting guess = 1497208734.Which i thought i fix it in my while loop?

Comment: have tried rnd.nextInt(50)? This will limit the range of the random number

Comment: No.I thought i can use the while loops to limit the range too?It makes sense to me.

Comment: Does that mean i have to change the conditions in my while loops?

Comment: @user2179615, the while loop will still print even if the number is not in the range [1..50]. Here's why: Let's say you're at the first iteration of your loop. i equals 1, so the condition satisfies. nextInt() generates a random number, let's say 100. It then prints this number and stops, because i is not in range [1..50].

Comment: If you want to make your program more effective, once the random number generated, make sure it didn't been tested before if so, just regenerate another random number.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the bound in your `rnd.nextInt();` in your case I guess

```
rnd.nextInt(50) + 1; // (1 - 50)
```

and review your condition otherwise your program will never stop

```
while(i>=1 && i<=50)
```

Have a look at the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Following is the declaration for java.util.Random.nextInt() method.

```
public int nextInt(int n)
```

Parameters
n--This is the bound on the random number to be returned. Must be positive.

Return Value
The method call returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive).

Comment: It works.But something is strange.When i input my numbers,the last line keeps giving me guess=0.

Comment: Since he wanted to exclude 0, it should be `rnd.nextInt(50) + 1`.

Comment: @user Take a look at this code `while(i>=1 && i<=50)` and find out what's wrong. When do you want the program to stop guessing?

Comment: and I think when the number has been guessed? I don't see anything to test that in your code. You can remove the test `i>=1 && i<=50` because i will always be between 1 and 50 and replace the test when the number generated has been guess.

Comment: @user The `while` statement has nothing to do with which numbers the program is allowed to guess. `rnd.nextInt` takes care of that. Take another look at your assignment description and see when the program should finish guessing.